# How to sum the values in a text file?

Tags: r

I am trying to add all the values in a text file composed of entries like the following:

1 0 1 1 1

1 0 1 0 1

0 0 0 1 1

In short, there are 200 rows and with 5 entries in each row. I am trying to find the sum of all the digits. But I have no idea how to do this.

I began by importing the text file using:

```
 mydataset = read.table(file.choose(),header=FALSE)
```

But after that, how do I go about adding all the values? I was thinking of using two nested loops to sum all the indices of this 2D vector , but I don't know how to perform this using R.

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Or just `sum(mydataset)`

Comment: And directly from file - `sum(scan(file))`

Comment: Thank you Rhertel and Richard!

Comment: You're welcome, @CivilSigma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic function `sum()`with your `mydataset`as only argument *i.e.*`sum(mydataset)`, can do that for you.

This is quite a trivial question and if you are looking to do simple things, you will most likely be able to find it [here](http://www.statmethods.net/management/functions.html).